# 12.04 Package System Broken apt-get autoremove -f fails

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates, package-management

I am trying to install all of the latest updates for Ubuntu 12.04.

New hardware support and `linux-image-3.11.0-26-generic` (New install) 57.1MB are what I have remaining.

Update Manager tells me "Package System Broken" and suggests I use `apt-get autoremove -f` to fix unmet dependencies.

Running this gives me an error with no additional tips on how to fix it. Here is my terminal output:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove -f
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.11.0-26-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-lts-saucy-doc-3.11.0 linux-lts-saucy-source-3.11.0
  linux-lts-saucy-tools
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libindicate-gtk3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.11.0-26-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/57.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 154 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 168779 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.11.0-26-generic (from .../linux-image-3.11.0-26-generic_3.11.0-26.45~precise1_i386.deb) ...
This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.11.0-26-generic_3.11.0-26.45~precise1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.11.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.11.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-26-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.11.0-26-generic_3.11.0-26.45~precise1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here are the results from what fkraiem suggested. I edited my grub file to read:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash forcepae"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="forcepae"

I updated my grub configuration and rebooted. I tried running apt-get -f install again. I am experiencing the exact same output as above though. It seems adding the forcepae switch did not do anything.

apt-get autoremove fails as well, suggesting I run apt-get -f install which produces the output seen above. I am unable to install any updates or programs.

This is an HP Compaq nc4010 with a 1.7ghz Pentium M

Comment: @fkraiem, I had tried google and looking here on the forums but didn't find any similar results. Thank you for showing me which part to lookup, sometimes it helps just knowing what terms to use when searching. I have updated my post with the results.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search for this error message

```
This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU.
```

seems to indicate that this is a common problem. Apparently, on some systems the kernel fails to recognise that the CPU supports PAE, which is required by Ubuntu. A solution seems to be to boot with the `forcepae` kernel option, so try this:

1. Open `/etc/default/grub` in a text editor. You can do for example `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`.
2. You will have a line of the form `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="something"`, add `forcepae` so that the line becomes `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="something forcepae"`. Save your changes and exit your text editor.
3. Run `sudo update-grub`, reboot, and try `sudo apt-get -f install`.